# How to understand the files in a PyCharm project?

Tags: python, django

How to understand the files in the PyCharm project?

[image]

As the snapshot shows, there are so many files:

1) Type-1, with `.`start: `.eslintignore`, `.eslintrc`, `.gitignore`, `.gitreview`...

2）Type-2, `.cfg` files: `babel-django.cfg`, `babel-djangojs.cfg`

3）Type-3, `.rst` files: `CONTRIBUTING.rst`, `HACKING.rst`

4）Type-4, `Makefile`

5）Type-5, `MANIFEST.in`

6）Type-6, `package.json`

7）Type-7, `requirements.txt`

8）Type-8, `setup.cfg`

9）Type-9, `setup.py`

What does these files means? what function do them have?

Comment: This IDE supports multiple language ..All the above are extension.Your project may include multiple type of file .Pychar can understand all the those

Comment: @HariomSingh Do you mean I can delete all the `1) -9)`  files?

Comment: Did you  got this build from git ...if you don't want to use pycharm to auto upload /commit  or sync file to git you can remove all